# how to activate page with out create version in author instance

Tags: aem, aem-6

When we do modifications in page activate page it will be creating version.

Is it possible disable version when we activate page.

To configure the Version Manager
PID com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.VersionManagerImpl
versionmanager.createVersionOnActivation (Boolean, default: false)

If we click uncheckbox, when activate page I am able to disable versions.
but above one will be affect all projects.

Any other way do disable versions for specific project?

Below thing also creating versions

by  programatically
  replicator.replicate(session, ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE,pagepath);

[enter link description here](http://How%20to%20replicate%20a%20page%20and%20all%20its%20children%20using%20replicator%20API?)

Comment: /jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage/d1/11/0d/d1110d19-3387-47bb-a9ca-86a58978239c/1.0              i don't create versions

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the version creation by enabling the "no version" flag in the replication agent settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different [method for replication](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/replication/Replicator.html#replicate(javax.jcr.Session,%20com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationActionType,%20java.lang.String,%20com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationOptions)), pass [ReplicationOptions](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/replication/ReplicationOptions.html#setSuppressVersions(boolean))

```
void replicate(Session session,
               ReplicationActionType type,
               String path,
               ReplicationOptions options)
               throws ReplicationException
```

In ReplicationOptions, there is a way to suppress the implicit version

```
public void setSuppressVersions(boolean suppressVersions)
```